# Why do unsafe .run() call works fine on a null value in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I have the following code fragment:

```
val foo: String? = null
foo.run { println("foo") }
```

I have here a nullable variable `foo` that is actually set to `null` followed by a nonsafe `.run()` call.

When I run the code snippet, I get `foo` printed out despite the fact that the `run` method is called on a `null`. Why is that? Why no `NullPointerException`? Why does compiler allow a nonsafe call on an optional value?

If I pass `println(foo)`, I get a nice juicy `null` in the console so I think it's safe to assume that `foo` is actually `null`.

Comment: `foo.run { if (this == null) doThis() else doThat(this) }` is totally legit. The usability is debatable.

Comment: simply because `'run` is an extension method on a generic type T and the block is also an extension method on T.  The variable `foo` value isn't what's important, it the inferred type.  `foo` is passed to the block as `this`, and as long as `this` is not use, a `null` valued `foo` is safe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe, there are two things that both might be of some surprise: the language semantics that allow such a call, and what happens at runtime when this code executes.

From the language side, Kotlin allows [nullable receiver, but only for extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#nullable-receiver). To write an extension function that accepts a nullable receiver, one should either write the nullable type explicitly, or use a nullable upper bound for a type parameter (actually, when you specify no upper bound, the default one is nullable `Any?`):

```
fun List<*>?.isEmptyOrNull() = this == null || size == 0 // explicit nullable type
```

```
fun <T : CharSequence?> T.nullWhenEmpty() = if ("$this" == "") null else this // nullable T
```

```
fun <T> T.identity() = this // default upper bound Any? is nullable
```

This feature is used in `kotlin-stdlib` in several places: see [`CharSequence?.isNullOrEmpty()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-null-or-empty.html), [`CharSequence?.isNullOrBlank()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-null-or-blank.html), [`?.orEmpty()` for containers](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/or-empty.html) and [`String?.orEmpty()`](http://String?.orEmpty()), and even [`Any?.toString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html). Some functions like [`T.let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html), [`T.run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) that you asked about and some others just don't provide an upper bound for the type parameter, and that defaults to nullable `Any?`. And [`T.use`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/use.html) provides a nullable upper bound `Closeable?`.

Under the hood, that is, from the runtime perspective, the extension calls are *not* compiled into the JVM member call instructions [`INVOKEVIRTUAL`](https://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--35.html), [`INVOKEINTERFACE`](https://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--32.html) or [`INVOKESPECIAL`](https://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--33.html) (the JVM checks the first argument of such calls, the implicit `this`, for being null and throws an NPE if it is, and this is how Java & Kotlin member functions are called). Instead, the Kotlin extension functions are compiled down to static methods, and the receiver is just passed as the first argument. Such a method is called with the [`INVOKESTATIC`](https://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--34.html) instruction that does not check the arguments for being null.

Note that when a receiver of an extension can be nullable, Kotlin does not allow you to use it where a not-null value is required without checking it for null first:

```
fun Int?.foo() = this + 1 // error, + is not defined for nullable Int?
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to what @holi-java said, there is nothing unsafe about your code at all. `println("foo")` is perfectly valid whether `foo` is null or not. If you tried something like

```
foo.run { subString(1) }
```

it would be unsafe, and you will find it won't even compile without some sort of null check:

```
foo.run { this?.subString(1) }
// or
foo?.run { subString(1) }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the top-level function `run` accept anything `Any` & `Any?`. so an extension function with [Null Receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#nullable-receiver) doesn't checked by Kotlin in runtime.

```
//                 v--- accept anything
public inline fun <T, R> T.run(block: T.() -> R): R = block()
```

**Indeed**, the inline function `run` is generated by Kotlin without any assertions if the `receiver` can be *nullable*, so it is more like a noinline function generated to Java code as below:

```
public static Object run(Object receiver, Function1<Object, Object> block){
   //v--- the parameters checking is taken away if the reciever can be nullable
  //Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(receiver, "receiver");

  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(block, "block");
  // ^--- checking the `block` parameter since it can't be null 
}
```

**IF** you want to call it in a safety way, you can use [safe-call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls)  operator `?.` instead, for example:

```
val foo: String? = null

// v--- short-circuited if the foo is null
foo?.run { println("foo") }
```